# Is it still possible to get the "defeat a 2x enemy" voucher without losing soldiers?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

This game (called Streetpass Battle or Warrior's Way depending on your region) has a voucher that you can get when you defeat an enemy whose army is at least 2x the size of yours.

I currently have more than 5,000,000 soldiers and, as the maximum amount seems to be 9,999,999, it's impossible to meet an enemy that fits this description.

Is losing in battle enough times to get to 4,999,999 soldiers or less the only way for me to get that voucher now?

Comment: Since the tags are not synonimised, using just "warrior's way" limits the appearance of this question. I replaced it with the tag suggested in the accepted answer in this relevant meta question: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/mii-plaza-mini-games-have-different-names-worldwide-than-in-the-us-can-the-tags/

Comment: I have [suggested the synonyms](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/streetpass-mii-plaza/synonyms), there is also [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7494/28182) question where we discussed what to do with them :)

Comment: @Robotnik I hope we'll mantain a tag for each minigame, we should "synonymize" only the USA and the worldwide variant, imho.

Comment: @pinckerman - Is there a need to? The reason there was no movement on this was because we couldn't decide which direction the overarching tags should be in. feel free to weigh back in on that meta if you wish to spur up the discussion again :), but I'm in agreement that, just like we don't have tags for wii-bowling etc, that these should all be synonymised with the plaza tag. Either way, I only suggested the synonyms in order to get some movement happening :)

Comment: @Robotnik If the amount of questions about Streetpass games remains as now, you are right. But this means that everytime someone asks a question about those games he has to specify the game in the title and that's what tags are made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid so.
A friend of mine had to do the same thing to achieve that voucher, that's a challenge you should try at the start of the game.